# About an elementary limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here we have an elementary limit that Mathematica simply doesn't want to compute it.
What solutions might I have to fix that? Could you help here? As you can easily guess,
the limit is precisely $0$.

Below you may find the code I used

```
N[Limit[Integrate[Sin[t^n], {t, 0, Pi/2}], n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]]
```

Comment: Since you already know the answer, why do you need Mathematica to compute it?  `Limit` and `Integrate` don't work together, only separately.  If the inner Integrate can't finish, Limit can't do anything.

Comment: @Szabolcs Out of curiosity. I expect Mathematica gives the correct answer, don't you think? This is not really true since one can put both Limit and Integrate together and they work, but not always.

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples where `Integrate` doesn't work alone, `Limit` doesn't work *on the integrand*, but `Limit[Integrate[...],...]` does work.  If you are, please let me know.

Comment: I'm more puzzled by the difference between `integ = Integrate[Sin[t^n], {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
  Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]` and `integ2 = 1/n Integrate[y^(1/n - 1) Sin[y], {y, 0, (Pi/2)^n}, 
   Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]`. Try `Table[integ // N // Chop, {n, 1, 100, 10}]` and `Table[integ2 // N // Chop, {n, 1, 100, 10}]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"What solutions might I have to fix that?"
As Szabolcs says, if the`Integrate`command does not return an expression,
other than`Integrate[...]`, then`Limit`has no chance to operate. So, I
would first find the integral by supplying`Integrate`with sufficient
assumptions:

```
Integrate[Sin[t^n], {t,0,Pi/2}, Assumptions :> {n>=1}]
```

The assumption of integer $n$ is not sufficient, but $n\ge1$ is sufficient.
The result involves the exponential integrals

```
ExpIntegralE[(n-1)/n, +I (Pi/2)^n]
ExpIntegralE[(n-1)/n, -I (Pi/2)^n]
```

and a Gamma function term

```
Gamma[1+1/n] Sin[Pi/(2n)]
```

The limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ of the Gamma function term is clearly 0, which
Mathematica easily finds. The limit of either ExpIntegralE term cannot
be found by Mathematica (I'm running v9). However, if you write

```
Limit[ExpIntegralE[a, I x], x->Infinity]
```

or

```
Limit[FunctionExpand[ExpIntegralE[a, I (Pi/2)^n]], n->Infinity]
```

Mathematica succeeds in finding the correct result for you.